# Can I hide some dropdownlist options dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down list that has 3 items:

```
label  value
"item 1"  1
"item 2"  2
"item 3"  3
```

Based on another drop down list's selection, I will either need to display 2 and 3 or just 1.

Is it possible to just use a single dropdownlist for this or should I have 2 of them and then somehow just hide/show either one?

Comment: How does the another drop down list look?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just like with any other DOM element you can give an ID to each option then toggle it's appearance like that, you'd probably want to do it within some function that is triggered by an event...

```
<select name="selection">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2" id="hid">2</option>
</select>
<script>
    document.getElementById("hid").style.display = "none";
</script>
```